# VLookup - Using InputBox to Determine Table Array Location

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with lots of tabs each one associated with a certain date.

I want a macro to pull out data from a column 'Theme' from `sheet1` and place it in `sheet2`.

`Sheet1` is determined by an input box which is completed by the user.

For example the user will type `9th September` to take the data from one sheet to another.

I have created the code and it works using `sheet1` and `sheet2` however I would like it slightly adapted as below:

- Sheet1 = current active sheet (`ActiveSheet` doesn't seem to be working)
- Sheet2 = This will be generated by the Input Box ("pin" in the code)

---

```
Sub Vlookup()

Dim pin As Variant
pin = VBA.InputBox("Enter Worksheet to lookup", "PIN")
If (pin = "") Then Exit Sub

[Sheet2!E2] = [VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!A1:X200, 5, FALSE)]

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet your requirements:

```
Sub Vlookup()

Dim pin As Variant
pin = InputBox("Enter Worksheet to insert", "PIN")
If pin = "" Then Exit Sub

Sheets(pin).Range("E2").Value2 = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Sheets(pin).Range("A2").Value2, _
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:X200"), 5, False)

End Sub
```

However there are some crucial things missing from your code, especially input validation. Your code does not check the user's input. So, if a user enters something else than a sheet name or simply mistypes your code will break. A simple solution would be using an error handler. A more elegant solution would be using a `UserForm` instead of an `InputBox`. On the `UserForm` you could have a dropdown list that shows all the worksheet names and lets the user select it.

Comment: Thank you so much that did it!  I changed around the 'activesheet...' and 'Sheets(pin)' etc to how I needed it but it worked perfectly.